# Aptana RadRails undefined method 'source'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana3

I recently installed linux and am trying my hand at ruby development. I have successfully installed rvm, along with rails and sqlite3. I created a test application in Aptana RadRails to make sure my install worked correctly.

Unfortunately, when I try to run my app I receive this error:

> /home/Daniel/Workspace/Dan_Test/Gemfile:1:in `<main>': undefined
>   method`source' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

I cannot figure out why I am receiving this error. The application is the default created under 'rails new'; I have added no new code. I have also run bundle install so the appropriate gems should be present.

Thank you very much for your help!

below is the gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:     https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Can you add your Gemfile to the question?

Comment: Looks like there is a missing `#` comment symbol at the `https...` line right above `gem 'turbolinks'`. Is that a typo in your post, or is that in the original Gemfile?

Comment: That is a typo, sorry.

Comment: @Daniel Gotcha. So how are you running the app; via `rails s` or `rails server` I assume?

Comment: That is correct; I am using rails server.

Comment: when you run "ruby -v" which version does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me; the issue was with how I installed rvm. I set a path that didn't exist in the bashrc: source /etc/provile.d/rvm.sh, instead of /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh. This seems to have caused the majority of my issues.

Thank you for your patience!